# Getting summary of results from another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have one complex stored procedure that returns some rows with some calculated values

```
SELECT  CalculatedField1 ,
        CalculatedField2 ,
        ...
FROM ...
WHERE CONDITION
```

this sproc (lets call it procA) returns variable number of rows, depending on the WHERE condition. This works fine. What I need to do now is to write a stored procedure that will get the summary of these returned rows.

```
-- procB
SELECT SUM(CalculatedField1),
SELECT SUM(CalculatedField2),
       ...
FROM (EXEC procA params)
```

Is this possible?

Edit: creating a temp table did the job, however I have problems with passing output pareters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sprocB] (@prm INT = NULL OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @prm = 1

    SELECT Id FROM dbo.AnyTable
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sprocA] (@prm INT = NULL OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #temp (Id INT)

    INSERT INTO #temp
    EXEC sprocB @prm

    SELECT Id FROM #temp
END
```

To execute:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
    @prm int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sprocA]
    @prm = @prm OUTPUT

SELECT  @prm as N'@prm'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

The results from temp table are ok, resultset is retrieved correctly, however @pem value is still NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but you need an auxiliary table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procB
AS

declare @table table (CalculatedField1 int, CalculatedField12 int)

insert into @table
EXEC sp_a

select SUM(CalculatedField1), SUM(CalculatedField2)
from @table

GO
```

Comment: I have a problem with output parameters. See the update in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you want:

> create table #scratch (CalculatedField1 int, CalculatedField2 int,...)
>
> insert into #scratch (exec procA params)
>
> select sum(CalculatedField1), sum(CalculatedField2),... from #scratch
>
> drop table #scratch

Comment: I have a problem with output parameters. See the update in the question.

Comment: You need to use a temp table (#tablename) rather than a table variable (@tablename).  Tables variables cannot be used in a INSERT EXEC or SELECT INTO statement.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305977/en-us

Comment: Hi Katherine, I get the same results from both declaring table variable and creating temp table. In both cases I get the data, but output parameters do not work.

Comment: Huh.  Well, clearly I don't have your stored procedure, but I did write a test where I executed one stored procedure into a temp table in another stored procedure and it worked fine.

Comment: There is no problem with getting resultset in temp table, as I said, there is a problem with it getting value from output parameter. Here is my scenario: both sprocA and sprocB have the the same signature (ex one out parameter prm). inside procA you call the procB by passing prm that was passed to procA (see my example). ProcB returns filtered set and it also sets a value for output parameter (=1). The problem is that after sprocA finishes, prm will still be null (original value when passed to procA), although we set it to 1 in sprocB. If I call procB from query window, @prm will have value 1.

Comment: I will update the main question to give you the exact code for stored procedures.